# How to get the index of the element in the List in SwiftUI when the List is populated with the array?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

In my SwiftUI app, I have a list of items.

I'm using the array of MenuItems to fill in the list

```
struct MenuItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
                    var id = UUID()
                    var text: String
}

struct MenuView: View {

var menuItems = [MenuItem(text:"Text1"),MenuItem(text:"Text2")]

                 var body: some View {

                  List {

                                ForEach(menuItems) {textItem in

                   Text(textItem.text)

             }

        }

        }

    }
```

The question is, how to get the index of textItem?

For example if I want to have different row colors for odd and even rows, or if I need to implement different styling for the row with number 3?

What is the best way to get the index of the item in the List in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using using `.enumerated`. For your `MenuItem` values it will be as follows

```
List {
    ForEach(Array(menuItems.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, textItem) in
        // do with `index` anything needed here
        Text(textItem.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore...
I'm getting Type '_' has no member '1'

Comment: @Muvimotv, it works for topic starter code. If it does not for your code, then you'd better post your own question with that code. ;)

Comment: It works but it does not perform great. In simple cases it is ok. But if you are using @FetchRequest and getting data from Core Data and do Array(items.enumerated()) then it works in suboptimal way, i.e. it loads all items at once. If you are storing thousands of rows in Item entity and want to have .fetchBatchSize = 10 defined then it at once executes all needed FetchRequests to load all data, if you do the same setup without this Array() enumereated() mix just ForEach(menuItems, id: \.self) it work performant and loads batched of 10 rows!